# Spring MVC why is data from my model not displaying in output.jsp?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm using Spring MVC. Why is data from my model not displaying in output.jsp?.  I am working on a very easy example of data coming out on one page and being display on the 2nd back. I checked to see if the data is in the model and it is but I don't know why the 2nd JSP is not displaying it.

Here is my control:

```
@Controller
public class RequestController {


    private static final Logger LOGGER = getLogger(RequestController.class);

    @RequestMapping(value = "/request" , method = RequestMethod.GET)
       public ModelAndView displayRequestPage(@ModelAttribute("inputForm") InputForm inputForm) {

        return new ModelAndView("input");

    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/request" , method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView displayOutputPage(@ModelAttribute("inputForm") InputForm inputForm) {

        Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        model.put("inputForm", inputForm);

        return new ModelAndView("display", model);

    }


}
```

here is my output JSP:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>JQuery Validation Engine</title>
</head>
<body>
 <center>
<h2>JQuery Examples</h2>
 </center>
        <p>Name: <c:out value="${inputForm.name}"/>
        <p>Phone(xxx)xxx-xxxxx: <c:out value="${inputForm.phone}"/>
        <p>Email: <c:out value="${inputForm.email}"/>

    <p>
     <b>Please  <a href="./request">click here</a>  to restart</b>
    </p>

</body>
</html>
```

this is what I am getting as output:

```
Name: ${inputForm.name}

Phone(xxx)xxx-xxxxx: ${inputForm.phone}

Email: ${inputForm.email}

Please click here to restart
```

Here is my Spring MVC.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"

    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

  <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource"
          p:basenames="messages" />

    <!-- Declare the Interceptor -->
    <mvc:interceptors>
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor"
              p:paramName="locale" />
    </mvc:interceptors>


    <mvc:resources mapping="/static/**" location="/WEB-INF/static/"/>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

I got it working but changing my web.xml.. Below is the working web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">


  <display-name>JQuery Example Web Application</display-name>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-config.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value></param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

and here is the web.xml that did not work:

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

  <display-name>JQuery Example Web Application</display-name>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-config.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value></param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Can someone please tell me why change the web.xml made it work.

Comment: What ViewResolver are you using?

Comment: <bean id="viewResolver"
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
  <property name="viewClass"
   value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
  <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
  <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
 </bean>

Comment: Looks like your EL is not evaluated. You might want to try this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1721518/738746.

Comment: I removed this line from web.xml and everything works now.. 

<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your model is only populated for POST requests (in `displayOutputPage`), but nowhere in your JSP do you submit a form.  Therefore, you only ever call `displayRequestPage` and never provide a model (a `<a href` creates a GET request).

Furthermore, because you are not submitting a `<form>`, your `inputForm` will not have any data in it.

To check this, you can always set breakpoints and see which method is called.

EDIT:

I made the above assumption because you have the following link to restart the process:

```
<b>Please  <a href="./request">click here</a>  to restart</b>
```

And as your mapping for `displayRequestPage` is `/request`...  As to the EL not being evaluated, it may just be that because you don't have an `inputForm` as you have no model and therefore the EL doesn't evaluate it just prints the text as is.

EDIT2:

The EL expressions did not work for you previously because Servlet Spec 2.3 does not support EL (was introduced with 2.4).  As you had declared your `web.xml` to be using spec 2.3, it simply switched off the overhead of parsing for EL.

EDIT3:

Just to clarify the line

The line

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >
```

told your servlet container to use spec 2.3

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: quite possibly, if that's the case I'll remove my answer, but it seemed a bit long for a comment.

Comment: He found his answer, see his question comments. Leave this for future reference.

Comment: yes.. I am going to post how I got it work due to not understanding why it works. now.

Comment: I added but web.xml files. working and not work versions... can someone please tell me why it works now!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a `model` parameter to your controller methods and try to populate that model rather tha creating a new one.

Answer (score 0):

See also: [Basic Spring MVC Data Binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10198335/basic-spring-mvc-data-binding)

A couple of things that could be wrong:

- Make sure InputForm has getters/setters and a no-arg constructor
- Try using Spring's [bind tag](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.1.5/taglib/tag/BindTag.html) or form tag.
- Try just manually adding InputForm to the model (ie model.put()).

If your expecting InputForm to be data bound to the request you might need to use `@Valid`... you shouldn't but it would not hurt.

Finally on a successful POST you almost always want to redirect and not serve the response directly. If its an error you should serve the response.

Comment: I added but web.xml files. working and not work versions... can someone please tell me why it works now!