# how to bind multiple values in spring bean and show on jsp page

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-bean

i have values like

1. class 1
   (i). user 1 name
   (i). user 1 age
   (ii). user 2 name 
   (ii). user 2 age...
2. class 2
   (i). user 1 name
   (i). class 1 age
   (ii). user 2 name 
   (ii). user 2 age...
3. class 3
   (i). user 1 name
   (i). user 1 age
   (ii). user 2 name 
   (ii). user 2 age...
4. class 4
   (i). user 1 name
   (i). uesr 1 age
   (ii). user 2 name 
   (ii). user 2 age...

i want to store it in bean and display it on "JSP" page using model attribute....please help me

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10198335/basic-spring-mvc-data-binding

Answer (score 0):

I am getting your question properly,

1) Is it a list of same POJO's or different POJO's? 
2) If it is a list of same POJO's  Please go through this post [How to send list of Objects to View and back to Post method in controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15480397/how-to-send-list-of-object-to-view-and-back-to-post-method-in-controller)

Hope it will help

Thank You