# How to send ajax request data as a class to Spring mvc controller?

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

I am sending an AJAX request to a Spring MVC controller, like this:

```
var filters = {
    visual: visual, 
    Name: params['Name'], 
    Address: params['Address'], 
    documentType: params['documentType'], 
    itemQualifier: getItemQualifier(),
    itemIdentifier: params['itemIdentifier'], 
    currency: getCurrency(), 
    sellSide: getSellSide()
};

$.ajax({                                                                    
    type: "POST",
    url: "/reports/savefilters",
    data: filters,
    success: function(response) {
        alert('filters saved successfully: ' + response);
    },
    error: function(e) {
        alert('Error while saving filters: ' + e.message);
    }
});
```

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/savefilters", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String saveFilters(@RequestParam("visual") String visual, @RequestParam(value = "Name[]", required = false) String[] Name, 
        @RequestParam(value = "Address[]", required = false) String[] Address, @RequestParam(value = "documentType[]", required = false) String[] documentType, 
        @RequestParam("itemQualifier") String itemQualifier, @RequestParam(value = "itemIdentifier[]", required = false) String[] itemIdentifier, @RequestParam("currency") String currency,
        @RequestParam("sellSide") String sellSide, HttpServletRequest request)
{
    try
    {
        System.out.println("saveFilters");
        new DisplayService().saveFilters("ID", visual, Name, Address, documentType, itemQualifier, itemIdentifier, currency, sellSide);
        return "success";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return "error occured while inserting/updating db";
    }
}
```

I want to pass all these arguments as a class instead of sending like this.

How can I pass as a class from an AJAX call and how do I receive it in the Spring MVC controller code? Any suggestions please? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10198335/basic-spring-mvc-data-binding

Comment: Thanks for the comment @RoryMcCrossan. I think this post doesn't answer my question. I tried with model attribute but it's not working

Answer (score 1):

You can use the request object and using it you can get all the params as below.

```
public @ResponseBody String saveFilters(HttpServletRequest request){

String visual = request.getParameter("visual")

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. It is working with single values like visual but not with array parameters like name. I tried to get array values using request.getParameterValues() method also but couldn't get.

Comment: For the array, you have to use the  to get the array of params    and then process it.                                                    Map parameterMap = request.getParameterMap();                                                                         http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7312436/spring-mvc-how-to-get-all-request-params-in-a-map-in-spring-controller. If it resolves issue please do accept the answer as correct:)

Comment: This works when key and value are both Strings. value is coming as null If value is array like partnerName.

Comment: Did you try to get like this for arrays. Map parameterMap = request.getParameterMap();

Comment: yes. I tried like that. Map parameterMap = request.getParameterMap();
  if(parameterMap != null){
   System.out.println(parameterMap.size());
   System.out.println(parameterMap.get("KPI").toString());
   System.out.println(parameterMap.get("partnerName"));      }

Comment: What's the partnetName. i.e How the array looks like ?

Comment: Sorry. It is Name. It is typo. Array values are comma separated. I am able to see all the names when I print client(JS) side. Spring mvc is giving this value as null

Comment: Did you try something like this ?                                                        Map map = request.getParameterMap();
  for(Object key : map.keySet()){
   Object value = map.get(key);
  }.

Comment: Here both key and values are Objects, but if you know the data types of key and values, then you can cast like that

Comment: Hi Hemachandra, is it working ? You can loop through all of the keys in the array and get those values

Comment: yeah Sivakumar. I tried all these things but they are not working.

Comment: Can you post your array object that you are posting from client end ?

Comment: ["NEWPHASE1", "Supply", "PERF_1", "PERF_2", "Rajesh_B_2", "SBD"]